# How to generate excel report with aspose cells that has dynamic date columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, aspose-cells

As I am new to Aspose as well as oracle , facing trouble in generating excel.I want to generate a excel file from aspose .net. The problem of mine is as follows:

I have a data in coming out from oracle database in the following format:

```
Supervisor_Name Tel_No  Assigned_Date   Emp_Name    Job Color
Jacob Andrew    121 10/10/2016  Robert  A11 Green
Jacob Andrew    123 10/10/2016  David   A12 Red
John    214 10/10/2016  Kristen A13 Blue
John    32211   11/10/2016  Garry   B11 Orange
John    55454   11/10/2016  Martin  B32 Blue
```

For this I have joined multiple tables based on the requirement.

The problem is , I want this data in Excel in the following manner:

```
                              Mon        Tue
                              10         11
**Supervisor_Name Emp_Name**  
Jacob Andrew      
00121             Robert      A11
00123             David       A12
John              
                  Kristen     A13
                  Garry                  B11
                  Martin                 B32
```

I am not able to fetch the data in this format from oracle as well, if that would have worked it could have easier my code. But now as i am unable to fetch the data in the manner described above, Please suggest me a way by which i can accomplish this.

I am trying to achieve this in code side but stuck somewhere because of architecture.

```
public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable<T>(List<T> sourceList, List<ExcelCol> col)
        {
            DataTable ExDataTable= new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
            DataRow newRow = null;
            Dictionary<string,List<string>> dictCheck = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>(); // For adding a supervisor and his corresponding records

            return ExDataTable;
        }
```

What i am doing is trying to convert the data in data table in the format i want. But that doesn't seems to help me. Please can anyone suggest me a way/ approach to do this kind of task. Any help from anyone would be highly appreciated. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Please post this issue in [Aspose.Cells forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx) as we need to investigate this issue thoroughly. We will look into it and suggest you a sample code or workaround to deal with it.

**Note:** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose